# JSLint doesn't approve requestAnimationFrame(). Why?

Tags: javascript

Here is the code that JSLint approves but doesn't run in the browser:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var c = canvas.getContext("2d");
var x = 250;
var y = 250;

canvas.width = 500;
canvas.height = 500;

function requestAnimationFrame() {"use strict"; }

function animate() {
    "use strict";
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    c.beginPath();
    c.strokeStyle = "#29d070";
    c.arc(x, y, 40, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    c.stroke();
    x += 1;
}
animate();
```

And here is the code that JSLint doesn't approve but runs well in the browser:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var c = canvas.getContext("2d");
var x = 250;
var y = 250;

canvas.width = 500;
canvas.height = 500;

function animate() {
    "use strict";
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    c.beginPath();
    c.strokeStyle = "#29d070";
    c.arc(x, y, 40, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    c.stroke();
    x += 1;
}
animate();
```

So all I did is I just removed `function requestAnimationFrame() {"use strict"; }`. JSLint however started whining about requestAnimationFrame() not defined and bla bla bla. How to define it in JSLint and still run the code?

Comment: JSLint has options. One of those options is to assume a browser. Enable that.

Comment: `requestAnimationFrame()` is a function defined on the global object (`window`) within browsers. You need to assume a browser or use `window.requestAnimationFrame()`. Outside of a browser context, this function is not defined by the environment.